# zend framework2 proper way to basic login authentication

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm currently learning Zend2. My first attempt is create secured application with basic login form. So my first idea was to create a common SecuredController, that checks for user identity in his constructor and redirects if necessary. I saw that solution for Zend1 and was working:

```
class SecuredController extends AbstractActionController
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $auth = new AuthenticationService();

        if ( $auth->hasIdentity() ) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute("ts");
        }

        return $this->redirect()->toRoute( "login" );
    }
}
```

Then extending some other controllers used throughout appliation:

```
class MainController extends SecuredController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

I omitted LoginController and IndexController(same as MainController now), but you get the idea how it is set up. Confing for module looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Main;

return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Main\Controller\Secured' => 'Main\Controller\Common\SecuredController',
            'Main\Controller\Login' => 'Main\Controller\LoginController',
            'Main\Controller\Main' => 'Main\Controller\MainController',
            'Main\Controller\Index' => 'Main\Controller\IndexController',
        ),
    ),

    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Main\Controller\Index',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'main' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/ts[/][:action]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Main\Controller\Main',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'login' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/login',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Main\Controller\Login',
                        'action' => 'login',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'logout' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/logout',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Main\Controller\Login',
                        'action' => 'logout',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions' => true,
        'doctype' => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template' => 'error/404',
        'exception_template' => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/login' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/login.phtml',
            'layout/layout' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/main/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404' => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),

    'doctrine' => array(
        'driver' => array(
            __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
                'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => array( __DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity' )
            ),
            'orm_default' => array(
                'drivers' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
                )
            )
        )
    ),
);
```

But unfortunately its not working I have error:

```
Url plugin requires that controller event compose a router; none found
```

Anyone has a clue how implement my scenario? Securing whole aplication and redirecting to /login route users without identity.

Answer (score 4):

Add in your super controller.

```
namespace Admin\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;
...

class AdminController extends AbstractActionController
{

public function onDispatch(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e)
{
    /**
     * Verifica se o usuario se encontra logado, caso contrario redirecion ele para o login
     */
    $this->authService = new AuthenticationService();
    if(!$this->authService->hasIdentity()){
        $this->redirect()->toRoute("login");
    }
        return parent::onDispatch($e);
}
 ...
}
```

I believe this will work in your project design.

Answer (score 0):

issue 1)

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute("ts");
```

You don't have a route named 'ts' in your config, you need to setup the route when using toRoute().

issue 2)

You aren't setting up AuthenticationService properly. You need to specify an adapter to use this.

Instead of instantiating it in the controller, define it in your ServiceManager config.

config:

```
'My\AuthService' => function($sm) {
    $auth = new \Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService();
    $auth->setAdatper(/**  LDAP or What ever **/);

    return $auth;
},
```

controller:

```
// already setup for you in the service manager
$authService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('My\AuthService');
```

You could always try zfcUser module if you want something out of the box tyo allow registering users etc:
https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser

Comment: AD.1 Isn't it in config? -> `'route'    => '/ts[/][:action]',`
AD.2 This might be source or problems?

I don't need any complicated mechanism. Just simple login form and all others Controllers except Login to be secured.

Comment: the name is the key in the array, which is what you refer to in toRoute() - the names in yours are main, home etc, try toRoute('home')

Answer (score 0):

[Authentication Module width login page](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/10/23/zend-framework-2-create-login-authentication-using-authenticationservice-with-rememberme/)